# If the linear transformation $T:U\to V$ projects $U$ onto a strict subspace of $U$, how to show the nullspace of $T$ is nontrivial?

Tags: linear-transformations

Given a linear transformation $T: U \rightarrow V$ that is a projection onto a subspace of $U$, given by the equation $\textbf{b} = T(\textbf{a})$, how do you show that the null space of $T$ is non-trivial? Note: the dimension of the subspace of $U$ is less than the dimension of $U$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the rank-nullity theorem. The rank (the dimension of the image) is the dimension of the subspace of $U$. But the rank and the nullity (the dimension of the null space) must sum to the dimension of $U$...